# cant get a right output xml file

Tags: java, xml, jdom

Im trying to make a xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package key="somekey">
<balance></balance>
</package>
```

but i am getting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <package key="somekey">
  <balance /> 
  </package>
```

the code is here:

```
public static void setXmlfile(){
     Element rootElement = new Element("package");
     Document doc = new Document(rootElement);
     rootElement.setAttribute("key","somekey");
     rootElement.addContent(new Element("balance"));

     try {
         XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
         outputter.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
         FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("javaXMLtest.xml");
         outputter.output(doc, fw);
         fw.close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
    }
```

Have try add Element or Content in different places, nothing.
May be i am using a wrong library? Please help for newbie!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean the same thing: `<balance></balance>` is identical to `<balance/>`

You can get what you want by configuring JDOM:

Empty elements are by default printed as `<empty/>`, but this can be configured with `Format.setExpandEmptyElements(boolean)` to cause them to be expanded to `<empty></empty>`.

http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html

Answer (score 0):

please use 
         outputter.setFormat(Format.setExpandEmptyElements(true));

Many thanks